# Error 1151 During Call to FB Credits API

Tags: javascript, facebook-credits

I try to use the Credits API on external site and get the following error in popup:

*API Error Code: 1151

API Error Description: Sorry, but this app may not be eligible to accept Facebook Credits. If this app has accepted credits before, please try again.

Error Message: Invalid Application*

As mentioned here:

[Facebook Credits. Error 1151](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7429519/facebook-credits-error-1151)

only FB canvas applications are eligible for this.

BUT!

If I take the popup URL and change the display parameter from *popup* to *page*, it works fine.

So, I'm wondering, can I use it on external sites or not?

Why does it work as *page* and doesn't work as *popup*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it work as page and doesn't work as popup?

Because it's explicitly designed that way, as the documentation clearly mentions:

> This dialog only supports desktop display modes: page. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/pay/)

And https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/ also very clearly states,

> Facebook offers a payments platform that enables developers to leverage our payments services to charge their users *on Apps on Facebook* as well as their *Mobile web Applications*.

Comment: Thank you for summing it all up.
I was really confused by info about unavailability of this API in external apps, spread all over the web.

Comment: Then another question arises. I would like to use popups for mobiles and pages for desctops. Is there a FB-preferable way to find out whether device is mobile or not? Maybe some list of user agents used by FB?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first link provided is no longer valid, here is the new equivalent: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/payments/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

We were getting this error code, but *on* the canvas. Just putting this up here in case anyone else is googling around and as stumped as we were.

We discovered that the payments dialog cannot be called from within a frameset. So, another reason to avoid framesets.